# STM32 storing data and logging history

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide, nucleo

I have a STM32 G491RETx board and the I have been trying to code in the CubeIDE environment. My aim has been to sample an ADC at 1MHz and record a timestamp in microseconds next to the value. The problem is if i try reading and logging it on the serial terminal it only reads to the nearest milliseconds. Does anyone know another way of storing ADC values and time data in microseconds?

I have tried using timers, DMA and poll for conversion and i cannot get a timestamp next to the adc OUTPUT.

Comment: If you drive the ADC from a timer, you already know the time difference between each sample. What more do you need? I guess it is not clear what you are trying to do. What do you mean by "timestamp"?

Comment: i mean the data being sent over the uart is as fast as the baud rate permits

Comment: Maybe you should show us your code then and it will be clearer. I don't know why you're attempting to run the ADC at 1MHz and also send the data over the UART. This seems doomed to failure.